# Git Hook Spellchecker Ignore Indented Lines

Tags: git, hook, ignore, aspell

I am writing a git hook that spell checks my commit messages. This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

ASPELL=$(which aspell)

WORDS=$($ASPELL list < "$1")

if [ -n "$WORDS" ]; then
    echo -e "Possible spelling errors found in commit message. Consider using git commit --amend to change the message.\n\tPossible mispelled words: " $WORDS
fi
```

I'm not sure how to tell aspell that I want to ignore lines that are indented (two or more spaces). This will avoid annoying messages about file names, comments, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you doing EECS 398 by any chance?

Just giving you a hint without breaking the honor code.

Put the commit message into a text file. Use a text editor to delete the indented lines from the text file. Then put the text file through aspell.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else comes across this and isn't in whatever college class the original poster was talking about, here's how I solved the problem:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ASPELL=$(which aspell)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Aspell not installed - unable to check spelling" >&2
    exit
else
    WORDS=$($ASPELL --mode=email --add-email-quote='#' list < "$1")
fi
if [ -n "$WORDS" ]; then
    printf "\e[1;33m  Possible spelling errors found in commit message.\n  Possible mispelled words: \n\e[0m\e[0;31m%s\n\e[0m\e[1;33m  Use git commit --amend to change the message.\e[0m\n\n" "$WORDS" >&2
fi
```

The key part being `--mode=email --add-email-quote='#'` arguments when we actually call `aspell`.

`--mode` sets the [filter](http://aspell.net/man-html/Notes-on-Various-Filters-and-Filter-Modes.html) mode, and in our case we're setting it to `email` mode. Which is described as:

> The `email` filter mode skips over quoted text. ... The option `add|rem-email-quote` controls the characters that are considered quote characters, the defaults are '`>`' and '`|`'.

So, if we add '`#`' to that list of "quote" characters, `aspell` will skip over it. We do that of course with the `--add-email-quote` option.

Note that we're also skipping over '`>`' and '`|`', per the documentation. If you don't want `aspell` to skip over these, use the `--rem-email-quote` option.

See [aspell's man page here](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/aspell1.html) for more info.